# Is it a good idea to store metadata in the column label of pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, metadata, pandas

I have been following the discussions about whether or not there should be a dedicated place to store `MetaData` in pandas `DataFrame` and I would personally find this feature very helpful.

Before this gets implemented in a future version, I have been looking at 2 workarounds, but none of them looks really satisfying.

Since I can't have a class inherit from `DataFrame`, I tried to make a class `MyDataFrame` that contains a `DataFrame` and implement all the methods `__add__`, `__mul__`...
However, this seems like a tedious approach given the number of methods available to manipulate the DataFrame.

Moreover, The data I manipulate originate from physical hardware (spectrum analyzers, oscilloscopes...) and in principle, I want to have a set of metadata (measurement bandwidth, number of averaging...) associated with each column of the dataframe. The structure that needs to be coded to maintain the one-to-one correspondance with the `DataFrame`'s structure looks complicated (what if the `DataFrame` gets Transposed ?)

I found an elegant solution would be to use custom objects instead of the usual names of the `Series` object. These "MetaIndex" are basically a string + metadata and would replace the usual column labels in `my_dataframe.columns` The class definition looks something like that:

```
class MetaIndex:
    def __hash__(self):
        return self.str.__hash__()

    def __eq__(self,other):
        return self.str == str(other)

    def __init__(self,st):
        self.str = format_name(st)
        self._meta = MetaData()

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.str


    def __str__(self):
        return self.str
```

Then when I save the `DataFrame` (in a hdf5 file), I change the `MetaIndex` into a regular string, and save each column's metadata separately, and when I load the data, I re-instantiate the column of the dataframe with something like:

```
s.replace_names_by_meta_index()
    for c in s.columns:
        col = s[c]
        if col.meta is not None:
            col.meta.set(**f["meta"][str(c)])
```

1) Would you say it's an advisable way to go, or is this a marginal and dangerous approach ?

2) Moreover, a very tempting extension is to have the MetaIndex inherit from str. In this way, the autocompletion still works with IPython (`my_dataframe.col1`). However, in this case, some simple operations like `my_dataframe.T.T` make the `MetaIndex` lose all the metadata contained in `index._meta` (as if behind the scene, the operation had reinstialized `index._meta = dict()`).
this looks very misterious to me, and that's also why I am worried about the whole approach.

Any clue about what's going on there ?
Thanks in advance,
Best regards,
Samuel

Comment: FYI, in 0.11, you can save metadata directly on the node where you save the frame itself, see here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/cookbook.html#hdfstore. doesn't directly answer your question, which actually is very tricky in the general case. You actually are associating a singular piece of data with the column name (the index element), so you don't have to deal with the ssue of how to propogate meta data, e.g. dfA + dfB (and its not a simple column label)

Comment: Thanks about version 0.11 (eventhough I still have a hard time working with the development versions since as a windows user I still didn't figure out how to have a proper C-compiler to work with pip). Concerning the propagation issue, I know that's what is making you sceptic about the feature, but what I am looking for is a system that works according to common sense in simple situations (initializing a DataFrame with a dict of series, or join an extra column), and drops the metadata that anyway would not be trustable in not-obvious-situations. I'm wondering if my suggestion works for this?

Comment: windows dev binaries are posted here (nd usually kept updated): http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-build/dev, this issue tracks the discussion on meta data in general, I added this question, which I think is a possibility for the future: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/3297